# Can spin_lock_irq()/spin_lock_irqsave() prevent priority inversion in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

From latest source code `spin_lock_irq()/spin_lock_irqsave()` disables preemption before acquiring the spin lock, assume `spin_lock_irqsave()` also disables interrupt in this case.

Is it safe to prevent priority inversion if both low and high priority tasks use `spin_lock_irq()/spin_lock_irqsave()` on the same lock?

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense as stated. If you have taken a spin lock and disabled interrupts and preemption (as those functions do), your task cannot be pre-empted in any way short of an NMI. Ergo, you have effectively boosted your task to the highest possible "priority" which it retains until it does a corresponding `spin_unlock_irqrestore`. I would say that in most cases, for kernel code, one _must_ usually disable interrupts/preemption when taking a spin lock in order to _prevent_ priority inversion. (But perhaps that's what you were asking?)

Comment: @GilHamilton Yes I think using spin_lock_irq() should be able to prevent priority inversion because it disables preemption as well as local interrupts in recent source code. However I am not sure if there is any corner case that I might be missing?